# Google drive as a system folder?

Tags: google-drive

Is there a way to use google drive on linux like it's another folder in the system so that I can save to it and see which files are remote?

Comment: See for instance https://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/

Comment: @Rinzwind I did do that but when I save say a tex document the drive isn't an option to save to, I'm pretty sure it's all remote too.

Comment: By default it does not sync. You need a sync tool for that (and you can then pick a normal dir, store files there and it will sync with gdrive). By default you only can access files from gdrive. (Oh: it is one of the last option in the link)

Comment: I don't get it. Do you like to have a sync folder or mount it on-the-fly ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few programs to do that. I can recomend [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki)